# How to precisely change the location of a FloatingAction Button?

Tags: flutter, button, dart

I have just implemented the package unicorndial 1.1.5 (https://pub.dev/documentation/unicorndial/latest/) in my app and it works like a treat. It is only used to display a key to different types of buildings that will be retrieved via a KML layer. The only problem I have is that the parent button (FloatingAction button) is under my bottom bar. I need to move it up by a specific number of pixels, so it displays just above the bar.

I have set the key up with this

```
// Map Key
    var childButtons = List<UnicornButton>();

    childButtons.add(
      UnicornButton(
          hasLabel: true,
          labelText: "Campus Buildings",
          labelHasShadow: true,
          labelShadowColor: Theme.UniColour.mapKey[50],
          currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "Campus Buildings",
            mini: true,
            backgroundColor: Theme.UniColour.mapKey[50],
            child: Icon(Icons.train, color: Theme.UniColour.mapKey[50]),
            onPressed: () {},
          )),
    );

    childButtons.add(
      UnicornButton(
          hasLabel: true,
          labelText: "University Residences",
          labelHasShadow: true,
          labelShadowColor: Theme.UniColour.mapKey[100],
          currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "University Residences",
            mini: true,
            backgroundColor: Theme.UniColour.mapKey[100],
            child: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active,
                color: Theme.UniColour.mapKey[100]),
            onPressed: () {},
          )),
    );
```

This is where I implement the code

```
home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          minimum: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 60.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _userLocation == null
                  ? showProgressIndicator()
                  : showMap(context),
              IconOptions(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: UnicornDialer(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
            animationDuration: 360,
            parentButtonBackground: Theme.UniColour.primary[900],
            orientation: UnicornOrientation.VERTICAL,
            parentButton: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
            childButtons: childButtons),
            floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniStartTop,
        drawer: MapDrawer(),
      ),
```

I thought I would try

floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat, but this has set values, such as endDocked and centerFloat, so it doesn't do what I need.

Does anybody know how to move the Floating Action Button a certain number of pixels up the screen, so my bottom bar is not hiding it?

You can just see the button under the settings cog of the bottom bar.

[image]

I have included a screenshot for you to see.

Comment: You should not use a FAB in floatingActionButton of a Scaffold but in the body of the Scaffold, so you can put it wherever you want.

Comment: Hi @huextrat, It won't let me put it anywhere else.

Comment: Why ? A FloatingActionButton is just a widget like others, I don't know UnicornDial but it should extends FloatingActionButton

Comment: All the articles I've seen on floatingActionButton has been at the end of body, not within it. for e.g.  body(),floatingActionButton

It even shows it there in the Flutter page - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your button with a stack and a positioned widget so you can control its position on the screen like this:

```
      floatingActionButton: Stack(children: <Widget>[Positioned(bottom: 40,right: 40,child: 
UnicornDialer(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
        animationDuration: 360,
        parentButtonBackground: Theme.UniColour.primary[900],
        orientation: UnicornOrientation.VERTICAL,
        parentButton: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
        childButtons: childButtons))],),
```

Whenever I pursue control over the position on the screen i go for the stack and positioned widget.
Also you can set the offsets of the Positioned based on the MediaQuery.of(context); 
So you can position it according to a relative size of the device

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've tried this , but the button has now gone and the map in no longer active. I need to have a play about with it I think.

Comment: That is strange. In the basic counter app it works as expected...although is a rather simple example. Try to debug the widget tree to see if you find something interesting from the map or the unicorn button. Happy debugging!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll keep you posted and thanks again for your input. Appreciated.

Comment: This was so easy to fix. I needed to include the width and height.

Comment: Thanks again. Always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code =>

```
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: () { print('Click'); },
),
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,
```